# Visual Studio 2013 - NuGet loads Restsharp 105.0 with Twilio library. Twilio is dependent on 104.4

Tags: nuget, restsharp

Is a new Twilio package on the way? I just signed up for your service and I'm getting the exception due to a dependency on RestSharp V104.4. Nuget installs Restsharp v105.0 with the Twilio library.

The error occurs when I hit this line:

```
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
```

Error is:

> Could not load file or assembly "RestSharp, Version=104.4.0.0..."

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the problem by installing the correct version of RestSharp through Package Manager Console.

[image]

Make sure you have the right default project selected in the dropdown and type:

```
Update-Package RestSharp -Version 104.4.0.0
```

This should make the problem go away.