# Twilio RestSharp Dependency

Tags: twilio, restsharp

I have just updated a MVC web application running on the ASP.NET Framework version 4.5.2.  I am using Twilio to send an SMS message:

```
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(twilioSid, twilioAuthToken);
var result = twilio.SendSmsMessage(twilioNumber, message.Destination, message.Body);
```

After the update, I am getting the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'RestSharp.HttpBasicAuthenticator' from assembly 'RestSharp,
>   Version=105.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The installed versions are:

- Twilio 4.0.4
- RestSharp 105.2.1

I have seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26744241/236860) posted back in November 2014 (8 months ago) and there is also some discussion on the [Twilio Nuget page](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) discussing an Alpha Version that is reported to remove the dependency on RestSharp.

Can anyone tell me what the status of the project is and what version options should be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We had to "lock" the [twilio-csharp library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install/) to [version 105.0.1](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio.Api/packages.config) due to the fact that every time RestSharp updates, we need to release a new version or fix bugs they introduce to the library. Seems they have just updated the library on August 16th which would have completely removed the Basic Authenticator module from the library

Now, since you're saying you updated RestSharp to version 105.2.1, I believe you will have done that by going to Nuget Package Manager and clicking Update All, which would then update your packages regardless of what is described on the packages.config file (even that file would then be updated).

To fix that, all you need to do, is go to your package manager console and run the following:

```
Install-Package RestSharp -Version 105.1.0
```

This will then revert your packages.config to use the correct version, and your project should work again.

[image: package manager console]

As for your second question, we have been working on an Alpha version that uses a stripped out version of RestSharp, but that is unfortunately not yet safe for production yet.

Hope this solves your problem.

UPDATE:
Just thought I'd add an update here to let you know I've now added [a new version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio/4.0.5) of the package that supports Restsharp 105.2.1

Comment: Hello Marcos - thank you for your fast and comprehensive answer - much appreciated.

Comment: @Marcos - Appreciate the answer, fixed my problem as well. I think one of the issues might be that the Twilio Nuget package has a RestSharp dependency of >= 105.1.0 - if you can restrict it to = 105.1.0 in Nuget, perhaps that would avoid the issue occuring?

Comment: @codechinchilla I've submitted a new version of the package as per my update above.

Comment: @MarcosPlacona no offense, but why not just use the Microsoft .NET HttpClient package? It's portable as well.

Comment: None taken. We just used what felt right at the time of building the project.

Comment: Twillio library does not work on DNXCore for the same reason and I have not found DNXCore support on RestSharp roadmap.

Comment: I'm assuming this is why the Twilio library no longer depends on RestSharp?

Comment: One of the reasons yeah. we wanted to move away from such breaking dependencies.