# Could not load type 'RestSharp.Authenticators.HttpBasicAuthenticator' from assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.1.0.0

Tags: twilio, restsharp

I have used a MVC web application running on the `ASP.NET Framework version 4.5.1`.
I have made `nopcommercePlugin`. I am upgrading version 3.4 to 3.5

After the update, I am getting the following error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
 'RestSharp.HttpBasicAuthenticator' from assembly 'RestSharp,
 Version=105.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

I am using `Twilio` to send an SMS message:

```
using Twilio;

public bool MethodName(string FromNumber, string ToNumber, string URL, string code = "")
        {

            if (code == "")
            {
                //URL = URL.Replace(" ", "%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20");
                URL = URL.Replace(" ", "%20");

            }
            else
            {
                URL = URL + code + " we repeat your code is : " + code;
                URL = URL.Replace(" ", "%20");
            }

            string AccountSid = _SMSProviderSettings.SMSGatewayTwillioAccountSID;
            string AuthToken = _SMSProviderSettings.SMSGatewayTwillioAccountAuthToken;

            var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

            var options = new CallOptions();
            var twimal = new Twilio.TwiML.TwilioResponse();
            twimal.Pause(5);

            options.To = ToNumber;

            options.Url = URL;
            options.From = FromNumber;
            options.Method = "GET";
            var call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);
            if (call != null)
            {
                if (call.RestException == null)
                    return true;
            }
            //error log entry in system log
            _logger.InsertLog(LogLevel.Error, call.RestException.Message, call.RestException.Message + " For more detail click here " + call.RestException.MoreInfo);
            return false;
        }
```

The Installed version are :

- Twilio.4.0.5
- Twilio.TwiML.3.3.6
- Twilio.Mvc.3.1.15
- RestSharp.105.1.0

I have seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067529/twilio-restsharp-dependency) posted back in 18th August 2015 (8 days ago) and there is also some discussion on the `Twilio Nuget` page discussing an Alpha Version that is reported.

If I used RestShrap 105.2.2 version then These errors are generate
[image]

Can anyone tell me what version options should be used?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When install Package for RestSharp through Package Manager Console, In RestSharp Folder there are multipal folder choose **net452-client** and install RestSharp dll.

After that my error has been solved.

Comment: That is not the answer to what you asked initially though. I have also created a sample project with the versions of Twilio you described here to check that it would work. https://github.com/mplacona/TwilioMVCSample/

Comment: I have download your code still getting above error which i was mention in my question.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. Consider using comments to post additional information that may be useful in some specific cases but are not entirely relevant to the question being asked.

Answer (score 8):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

RestSharp has been updated last week to [version 105.2.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/105.2.2). that caused the Twilio library to start failing since HttpBasicAuthenticator has been moved around to a different namespace.

The Twilio Library has then been updated to [version 4.0.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio/4.0.5) which now works with RestSharp version 105.2.2. The [packages file](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio.Api/packages.config) has also been updated to use that version.

So in short, all you should need to do is update your RestSharp to version 105.2.2 via Nuget Package Manager or via Package Manager Console by running:

```
Install-Package RestSharp
```

Comment: When add RestSharp 105.2.2 but getting build time error that TwilioRestClient , CallOptions assembly reference is missing

Comment: Please check in my question.

Comment: Can you update your question with your entire code? Seems like you're missing a `Using`

Comment: Please Check in question

Comment: Hey @Ajisha can you check whether my suggestion helped you fix your issue please? Happy to help further otherwise.

Comment: @MarcosPlacona Still getting the above exception with the twilio version 4.0.5 and restsharp 105.2.2

Comment: I have download your code still getting above error which i was mention in my question.